# How to display data in a drop down corresponding to the data from another dropdown in html page?

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I am trying to create a web page using Python DJANGO, in which I have two dropdowns out of which one is for category and another for subcategory, for which data is getting fetched from database. In DB, there are two columns for category and another for subcategory respectively.

For example, there are 2 Categories, i.e boys and girls. and for boys there are 3 names under SubCategory column, similarly for girls. So my want is that, in drop down 1, it should show 'boys' and 'girls'. When user chooses any of them, the corresponding names should appear in the second drop down(i.e only boys names should appear in dropdown 2 when "boys" is selected in dropdown1).

But the way I have written, its showing all the data irrespective of the selection in dropdown1. How can I make the subcategory data appear categorically?

View.py:

```
def createTicketView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        taskName=request.POST.get('title')
        taskDescription=request.POST.get('description')
        Category=request.POST.get('category')
        SubCategory=request.POST.get('type')
        user_id=request.user.id
        
        task=UserTaskDetails.objects.create(user_id=user_id,
                                           taskName=taskName,taskDescription=taskDescription,
                                             Category=Category,SubCategory=SubCategory)
        task.save()        
        return redirect('home')

    category =ServiceCategoryDetails.objects.values('category').distinct()
    subcategory=ServiceCategoryDetails.objects.values('SubCategory').distinct()  


    return render(request,'custws/ticket.html',{'title':'create ticket',
                                                'category':category,
                                                'subcategory':subcategory,
                                                '})
```

Html code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="category" class="font-weight-bold">Category</label>
            <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                {% for type in category %}
                <option value={{type.category}}>{{type.category}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="subcat" class="font-weight-bold">Sub Category</label>
            <select name="subcat" id="subcat" class="form-control">
                {% for type in subcategory %}
                <option value={{type.SubCategory}}>{{type.SubCategory}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use ajax. When user changes 1st input, ajax will update options of your 2nd input.
2. You could use [django-select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with dependent_fields option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Vit. I chose the Ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<form>
  ...
  <select id='subcat'></select>
</form>


$('#sub-btn').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {cat_id: <get_your_selected_id>}
    $.ajax( 
        { 
        type:"POST", 
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
        },
        url: "<your-url>", 
        data:data,
        success: function(data){ 
          // on success, dynamically append the select drop down list 
          $('#subcat').html(data)  
        }
    });
})
```

### VIEW

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cat_id = request.POST.get('cat_id')
        # create options, note: 'subcategories' should be replaced with your category related name
        options = [f"<option value='{i.pk}'>{i.value}</option>"+'\n'
                   for i in Category.objects.get(id=cat_id).subcategories.all()] 
        return HttpResponse(options)
```

Then, the success callback is called and the options are dynamically appended. You can also return `JsonResponse` of the data and construct the `option` element in frontend.

Besides, take a look of [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light), which is very convenient for doing autocomplete stuff and gracefully handles with all kinds of relations between fields

Comment: Thanks Minglyu. M able to execute the needful with the help of your guidance.